# Border layout in java

Tags: java, layout, set, border

I am following a java programming book and I just found something that I did not get.
In the following piece of code, more specifically in the constructor of the class "MainFrame"
we add a label and setting the layout of the frame at the same time, if I understand it correctly.
I thought we need to set out the type of the layout first and than to add elements to the frame.

```
package fontframe;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 300;

private JLabel label;
private JCheckBox italicCheckBox;
private JCheckBox boldCheckBox;
private JRadioButton smallButton;
private JRadioButton mediumButton;
private JRadioButton largeButton;
private JComboBox facenameCombo;
private ActionListener listener;

public MainFrame(){
    label = new JLabel("Big Java");
    add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
.......
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought we need to set out the type of the layout first and than to add elements to the frame.

Yes you are right, but the default layout of the `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` and for label is `FlowLayout`. So there is no need to specify the layout for the `JFrame` that it is already a BorderLayout.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html):

> And the child will be added to the contentPane. The content pane will
>   always be non-null.
>       Attempting to set it to null will cause the JFrame to throw an exception. 
>       The default content pane will have a BorderLayout manager set on it.

Comment: Oh right! That make sense! Thank you very much guys, you have made the picture much clearer! :)